# Azure Service Bus / Function with sessions, not waiting for function to complete

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Hi have an Azure Service Bus and an Azure function that takes the messages, with sessions enabled, and processes them. The function itself reads a Balance table to obtain the current balance, then adds/subtracts the balance, based on the amount in the message, then inserts a new record in to a Transactions table containing the amount and a new balance, like you would see on a bank transaction list. It also then updates the record in the Balance table.

The problem, is that when messages are coming in thick and fast, the first one picks up the Balance and begins to do the processing, but before it completes, the nest one has picked up the same balance rather than waiting for the first one to finish and then using the new balance.

This i an example...

[image: Example]

The first column is the amount and the last column the balance, and as you can see, both the top 2 messages have taken the balance of £7500.87 and added their amount to it. So the balance ended up being £26,791.22 instead of £70,624.73

The function signature is below...

```
[FunctionName("TransactionsQueueTrigger")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("transactions", Connection = "test_SERVICEBUS", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    // do some work on the balance
}
```

This is the host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The session identifier is simply for each account, so that i can have these running concurrently for different accounts, but not for the same account.

So, can i force the function to wait until the first one has completed(for that session) before starting another?

Comment: " like you would see on a bank transaction list." - this is not how a bank works and also, this is not how you should solve this problem. Take a look at Event Sourcing

Comment: In regards to the bank comment, i was just referring to how you would see the balance next to each transaction when viewing your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem, is that when messages are coming in thick and fast, the
> first one picks up the Balance and begins to do the processing,

First, try to put the logic in a async method and use await to make it wait:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp113
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue2", Connection = "str", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
            log.LogInformation($"Is loading...");
            await testc();
            log.LogInformation($"Completed!");
        }
        public static async Task testc()
        {
            //Some logic here.
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

If still not work, please try to use below host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, this may comes from the azure function app automatically scale out, so try to set the Maximum Scale Out Limit to 1:

[image]

Comment: I like the first answer, but on the second, isn't setting the maxConcurrentCalls to 1 going to cause everything to slow down when i have hundreds/thousands coming in?

Comment: I have tested the first solution but it didn't resolve the issue. I now believe that the message lock duration is kicking in(30 seconds) and the function gets the nest message. But not sure why it would hit 30 seconds, it isn't doing much. I have increased that temporarily to test the theory.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be to call an asynchronous Web API from the trigger function. Calls to the data updates within an API will force subsequent calls to block on an await call on the data context.

The data update on your transaction table can be processed through a stored procedure that will run under a single transaction that holds a read-write lock on the tables being updated and guarantees the consistency of the balance of the transaction.

This would ensure your trigger and data updates are decoupled and maintain consistency of the transaction.

Comment: Yes i guess this work but also need another component to process it. Effectively you are doing the same as Bowman's first answer below.

Comment: I agree Bowmans's solution is valid. When I gave my answer I was thinking of the connection limit of 600 per instance (unless you are using the Premium plan) and the number of concurrent messages running in the trigger may cause the connection limit to when connecting to the DB to exceed the limit unless you reuse / pool the connections or declare the connection statically (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections). I would advise more stress testing in the hundreds of messages to ensure concurrency and DB connections are not exhausted.